# Why all the records are not being copied from CSV to SQL table in a SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I am trying to copy data from a flat file to a SQL table using SSIS.
I have a Data Flow Task where I have created a Flat File Source pointing to the csv file and an OLE DB Destination pointing to the table I want the data in.
The problem I am facing is when I run the package, I get only 2621 rows copied to the SQL destination table, where I have about 1,70,000 records in the csv. Not sure why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a number of things. This is what comes to mind:

1. The connection string to your flat file is overwritten by a variable expression or a package configuration. Check `SSIS -> Package configurations` or the `Expressions` properties on your connection manager.
2. The `DataRowsToSkip` property on your flat file connection manager is set to a value.
3. The meta data definition of your flat file is incorrectly configured in your connection manager. See properties such as `Format`, `Row delimiter`, `Column delimiter`, etc. Use the preview function to see the output.
4. The error output on your flat file source is set to `Ignore failure`, meaning that lines which SSIS cannot process (due to, e.g., incompatible data types) are ignored without warning.