# ssis import skipping some lines

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

for some reason, I can't seem to figure out why I'm missing some lines when I import a csv file that I exported using sqlplus. The ssis package gives no warnings or errors as well.

The reason I know this is because when I loaded the csv file into a separate analysis application it gets the correct totals for numeric columns and row counts.

But for some reason, SSIS doesn't seem to capture all of the lines...

there were 6313052 rows in the csv file and ssis imports 6308607...

any thoughts?

I've tried different code pages too (1250, 1252, and UTF8) but they didn't seem to have an affect

I checked out this link:
[Why all the records are not being copied from CSV to SQL table in a SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537657/why-all-the-records-are-not-being-copied-from-csv-to-sql-table-in-a-ssis-package)

and numbers I've checked on numbers 2, 3, and 4.

Although, for number 1, I'm using a for each loop container descirbed in this site:
http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm
to loop through files in a folder and import them.

I've also thought about missing delimiters, but I exported the files myself using sqlplus like this:

```
select
trim(to_char(t1.D_DTM, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss'))||','||
trim(t1.TECHNOLOGY)||','||
trim(t1.VOICEDATA)||','||
trim(t2.MRKT_NM)||','||
trim(t2.REGION_NM)||','||
trim(t2.CLUSTER_NM)||','||
trim(t3.BSC_NM)||','||
trim(t1.BTS_ID)||','||
trim(t1.CSCD_NM)||','||
trim(t1.SECT_SEQ_ID)||','||
trim(t1.BND_ID)||','||
trim(t1.FA_ID)||','||
trim(t1.TCE_DTCT_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.MS_ACQ_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.SIGN_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.BAD_FRM_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.REORG_ATT_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.TCE_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.WCD_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.L_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.TRAF_FRM_MISS_CNT)||','||
trim(t1.BCP_TMO_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT)
from table
```

I'm not sure how I could miss delimiters if I export a file like that...

Also, I tested importing these files into MySql using LOAD DATA INFILE and that seems to work fine and import all of the data...

Comment: I've seen this when there are commas in the data items themselves. To take an example, if your "t1.MRKT_NM" column has an item like "UK, Ireland", then your row of data will end up having one comma too many. At that point, the last item of the row won't get read, and instead will be taken as the first column of the next row, and your CSV reading will be out of step. It plays hell with the import. Can you do a quick check for commas in all the character columns you're selecting from? (I've also seen it where character data had newlines embedded in it...)

Comment: I don't see any commans in the character columns...how do I check for newlines in character commas?

Comment: also, I don't think that there is commas in the char columns since the data is not out of place in those columns...

Comment: Is the Error Output setting on your destination set to "Redirect Row"?